# Wordpress dropdown suddenly not visible

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I made some edits to my wordpress / elementor site and suddenly my navbar dropdown isn't visible anymore. It kinda pops out but not correctly...

Been now using almost couple hours to identifyi the issue without success. Might this be a common issue with elementor astra theme users?

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ndd9.png)

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.